# How to sentinel loop that will add the users input and display the input?

Tags: c#

```
  class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int sum = 0;
            int count = 0;

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter all the numbers you would like to add. When finished, enter -1");

            string numbers = Console.ReadLine();

            while (numbers != "-1")
            {
                sum += int.Parse(numbers);
                count++;
                Console.WriteLine(sum);
                numbers = Console.ReadLine();

            }

        }
    }
```

When I run it, it adds the number right away. I need it so it won't also I can't have it close when the user types in -1. Any help would be grateful.

Comment: I don't understand your problem and your question.

Comment: I need it so it won't also I can't have it close when the user types in -1.??

Answer (score -1):

Here you go:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        int count = 0;
        int num = 0;

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter all the numbers you would like to add. When finished, enter -1");

        do 
        {
            string buffer = Console.ReadLine();

            if (Int32.TryParse(buffer, out num) && num != -1)
            {
                sum += num;
                count++;
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Entered: [{0}], Running total over [{1}] numbers is: [{2}].", num, count, sum));
            }
        }
        while (num != -1);
    }
}
```

Comment: I actually upvoted you and thank you for the help. It is much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks @Itsallgravy, did it work? (can you mark as answer if it did?)

Comment: Yes it did and I will